# Alert dialog text color using styles

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-styles

I have just updated the libraries version in my app and now the text color of the `AlertDialog` buttons are white. Before that it was the `colorAccent` attribute that specify them if I remember correctly. I've tried many different attributes and none of them seems to work.

Example photo - on the bottom right you can see the button that is pretty invisble:

[image]

My current alert dialog style:

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/website_main</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/website_main</item>
</style>
```

At my theme style:

```
<item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialogStyle</item>
```

Current version of support/design/appcompat I'm using is: `25.1.0`

Java code in which I create an `AlertDialog`:

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(activity.getString(R.string.ok), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    <UnrelatedLogic...>
                }
            });
    return alertDialogBuilder.show();
```

In here I use a `ListPreference` which also uses an `AlertDialog`:

```
android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference lang_preference = (android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference) findPreference("language_chooser");
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this a custom dialog?

Comment: No. Its a normal alert dialog, and it also happens at the default settings' dialogs.

Comment: can you post activity code where you are showing this alertdialog? It will help to answer the question.

Comment: Yes, in a moment.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It maybe usage for you.This is my [image]Alert Dialog Style :

```
<style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/teal</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/bg_3</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/bg_border</item>
    </style>
```

Usage of Style in Activity/Adapter

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext, R.style.AppCompatAlertDialogStyle);
```

Comment: The problem is that this is a specific solution. In my setting dialogs it also happenning so the solution has to be changing the main app theme.

Comment: This changes apply only for Dialog, not for whole app.

Comment: Same problem I am  facing

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit confusing, but `alertDialogStyle` is meant to style the `Dialog` box, not any child views that it contains (though, this apparently is not always the case). From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#ApplyingStyles):

> When you apply a style to a single `View` in the layout, the properties
>   defined by the style are applied only to that `View`. If a style is
>   applied to a `ViewGroup`, the child `View` elements will not inherit the
>   style properties—only the element to which you directly apply the
>   style will apply its properties. However, you can apply a style so
>   that it applies to all `View` elements—by applying the style as a theme.

Therefore, you must apply the style as a theme; which there is also an attribute for:

```
<item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogStyle</item>
```

Lastly, the `textColor` attribute *should* change the color of the title and body text, not the text color of the buttons. You should only need to apply the `colorAccent` attribute to color the button text:

```
<style name="AlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/website_main</item>
</style>
```

Comment: @DannyHambourg What does it do (if anything)? Also, what version of Android are you running it on? Lastly, try `alertDialogTheme` instead of `android:alertDialogTheme`; it could be something to do with AppCompat.